# Visual c++ for linux development. Warning: Cannot insert breakpoint - 1. Cannot access memory at address 0x720

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, visual-c++

**What i use:**

Windows 10 Enterprise.

Ubuntu 16.10 installed on VMWare. I installed gdb on machine.

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Visual C++ for Linux Development installed on it.

I have created a Console Application (Linux). Established a connection with my Ubuntu machine.

If I press Ctrl+F5 error appears. (See picture below)

[Ctrl+F5 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnCLP.png)

Either if I press F5 warning appears. (See picture below)

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyf4L.png)

I have my main.cpp. Here is the code.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    printf("Hello Ubuntu!");
    return 0;
}
```

In Ubuntu side if I run a gcc *.out(from bin directory) command via terminal, following message responsed.

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function _start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I researched over the internet, found some a bit similar problems without answers. I need help concerning this problem.

Comment: sounds like you didnt link the output

Comment: @jhbh what output I have to link? And with what? Provide please more details.

Comment: have a google for "g++ build and link". your error says that main is undefined. so it seems like a linker issue to me. That is about as much help as you can be given without knowing what your compile and link commands look like

Comment: look what happened. I changed Debug to Release and it works. But still the same error in Debug mode.

Comment: so look what happened when you changed from debug to release. and that will be your answer.